# How to insert comma-separated string value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure to add multiple players:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddMultipleUserofSameCountry]    
    @UserIds NVARCHAR(MAX),       
    @CountryCode INT,    
    @OwnsHasAccess INT,   
    @QryResult INT OUTPUT    
AS    
BEGIN TRY    
    SET @QryResult  = 0;    

    BEGIN TRANSACTION    
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO Players (CountryCode, UserId, OwnsHasAccess, InsertedWhen) 
        VALUES (@CountryCode,
                (SELECT Value FROM dbo.SplitString(@UserIds, ',')),
                @OwnsHasAccess, GETDATE());  
    END    

    COMMIT TRANSACTION    

    SET @QryResult  = 1;    
END TRY    
BEGIN CATCH    
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
    SET @QryResult  = 0;    
END CATCH
```

UserIds is comma-separated string value

DAL Code

```
array = string.Join(",", UserIds.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());

SqlParameter sqlParam = cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserIds", array);
sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
```

Please suggest is there any way to pass multple UserId to insert multiple players

Comment: You used the MySQL tag, yet the code looks more like being for SQL Server. Please check the tags and correct them if necessary. Please **also** add the tag for the specific version of your DBMS.

Comment: Is there a reason for not calling the procedure for every id? Does it have to be done all by one?

Answer (score 2):

You should build complete rows to use in the `INSERT` statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddMultipleUserofSameCountry]    
 @UserIds nvarchar(MAX),       
 @CountryCode int,    
 @OwnsHasAccess int,   
 @QryResult int output    
AS    
 Begin Try    
  Set @QryResult  = 0;    
  Begin Transaction    
   Begin  
       INSERT INTO Players(CountryCode,UserId,OwnsHasAccess,InsertedWhen)
       SELECT @CountryCode, Value, @OwnsHasAccess, GETDATE()
          FROM dbo.SplitString(@UserIds,',');  
   END    

   Commit Transaction    
   Set @QryResult  = 1;    

 End Try    
 Begin Catch    
  Rollback Transaction    
  Set @QryResult  = 0;    
 End Catch
```

Note: I am assuming `dbo.SplitString` works the same as `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2016

Comment: Here is [an SO article discussing a SQL Server SplitString implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428612/splitting-the-string-in-sql-server).