# Extract data between characters SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, character, extract

I am trying to retrieve random data between characters

Data Example:

```
ABC-33-Ha8o89-00
ABC-232-Ui7380-000
```

Out of the above example, I am trying to get Ha8o89 and Ui7380. Basically any data after two dashes from the left and one dash from the right.

Comment: which database provider are you using?

Comment: @arutar It is SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried? Will there _always_ be exactly three dashes? What do you want the result to be if there are no dashes, one dash, two dashes, or four+?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have tried the substring approach in which I tried to define starting at how many spaces from left I want to extract the values from for x amount of characters

select SUBSTRING(column, 8,6) as 'Field' from table
That's why I was seeking help for the dash approach. 

The problem with this approach is, the amount of characters before the extraction or after extraction could vary which is whs, it is always 3 dashes. 2 before and one after

Comment: You clearly can't use number of spaces / characters because the components aren't fixed size. Have you looked at `CHARINDEX`? Does the table have a key? What are the answers to my other questions (how many dashes)? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: And can a `.` appear _in the data_? Can the 3rd element ever be more than 128 characters?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It is always 3 dashes, two before and one after. No other special characters. The maximum amount of characters to be extracted is around 15. I believe it is version 2017 of sql server. I am not very familiar with charindex

Comment: I know exactly what direction you're going in, @AaronBertrand . ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using T-SQL, return nth delimited element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RandomData(StringValue varchar(128));

INSERT dbo.RandomData(StringValue) VALUES
('ABC-33-Ha8o89-00'),
('ABC-232-Ui7380-000');
```

A quick and dirty way, given that you state that there are *always* three dashes:

```
SELECT StringValue,
       Parsed = PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue,'-','.'), 2) 
       -- parsename starts right
  FROM dbo.RandomData;
```

On 2016+, you can use `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT r.StringValue, Parsed = j.value
  FROM dbo.RandomData AS r
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ('["' 
    + REPLACE(r.StringValue, '-', '","') + '"]') AS j
  WHERE [key] = 2; -- keys are 0-based
```

And on any version, you can use an ordered split function (there are dozens and dozens of examples out there), here's one I grabbed from [this article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/string_split-function-for-sql-2012-and-above) and [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69541144/61305):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitOrdered
(
    @list    nvarchar(max), 
    @delim   nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
RETURN
(
  WITH w(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0)) w(n)),
       k(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM w a, w b),
       r(n) AS (SELECT 0 FROM k a, k b, k c, k d, k e, k f, k g, k h),
       p(n) AS (SELECT TOP (COALESCE(LEN(@list), 0)) 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) -1 FROM r),
       spots(p) AS 
       (
         SELECT n FROM p 
         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@list, n, LEN(@delim + 'x') - 1) LIKE @delim OR n = 0)
       ),
       parts(p,val) AS 
       (
         SELECT p, SUBSTRING(@list, p + LEN(@delim + 'x') - 1, 
           LEAD(p, 1, 2147483647) OVER (ORDER BY p) - p - LEN(@delim)) 
         FROM spots AS s
       )
       SELECT listpos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p), 
              Item    = LTRIM(RTRIM(val))
         FROM parts
);
```

Then the query is:

```
SELECT r.StringValue, Parsed = s.Item
  FROM dbo.RandomData AS r
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitOrdered(r.StringValue, '-') AS s
  WHERE s.listpos = 3; -- listpos is 1-based
```

All three examples in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d38ded6de1736c4099202499faa07693).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHARINDEX` in a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to search for the first hyphen, then feed it in again to get the next hyphen and so on. Then you simply use `SUBSTRING` to get the correct value.

Use `NULLIF` to ensure it doesn't error out if the hyphen is not found

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  ThirdValue = SUBSTRING(d.StringValue, v2.Dash2 + 1, v3.Dash3 - v2.Dash2 - 1)
FROM dbo.RandomData d
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', d.StringValue), 0) )) v1(Dash1)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', d.StringValue, v1.Dash1 + 1), 0) )) v2(Dash2)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', d.StringValue, v2.Dash2 + 1), 0) )) v3(Dash3);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=102e50fc23c6d8a2a82ddcda3f914660)