# is there a way to use a mid-style function in sql like you can for excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

I have the following string of characters:

```
594074_Ally_Financial_TokioMarine_MD_SLDET_20210101_20211130_20211208
```

I am attempting to extract everything after the first '_' but before the '_TokioMarine', so the final string will look like:

```
Ally_Financial
```

Is this possible to do with SQL? I attempted but it was pulling the incorrect characters. I cant get the ones in between the values specified.

```
SELECT
@CurPolicyHolder = Right( DFH.FileName, CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName) - 1)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [the `SUBSTRING` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? Also, you should tag your specific DBMS, since the answer may depend on it.

Comment: Substring may be the case, im not sure how to apply it though but I am using SQL Server

Comment: Is the `_TokioMarine` a fixed value? Or are you looking for everything between the first and third `_` characters?

Comment: Its a fixed value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract data between characters SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609080/extract-data-between-characters-sql)

Answer (score 0):

To extract everything between the first `_` character and the `_TokyoMarine` string, you can use:

```sql
SELECT
    @CurPolicyHolder = SUBSTRING(DFH.FileName, CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName) + 1,
 CHARINDEX('_TokioMarine', DFH.FileName) - CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName) - 1)
```

[SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
[CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hey so " CHARINDEX('_TokioMarine', DFH.FileName) - CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName) - 1" is considered the length of this??

Comment: Yes, the third parameter is the length of the substring to return.